# Set height of View containing WebView based on content

Tags: react-native, webview

I want to set my WebView to be the same height as the content I want to display, nothing more.

I have a WebView wrapped in a View:

```
<View style={height: height}>
  <WebView
    ...
    onMessage={event => console.log(event.native.data)} // this returns height of element in px
  />
```

Inside the WebView, it is simply a `div`. I'm using `postMessage` to send to my React Native app, the height of the `div` on the WebView. How do I convert that number (in `px`) for styling in React Native?

I've tried using `PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize` but it was not right. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-autoheight-webview`, it will set height based on content.

```
import AutoHeightWebView from 'react-native-autoheight-webview'

import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

<AutoHeightWebView
    style={{ width: Dimensions.get('window').width - 15, marginTop: 35 }}
    customStyle={`
      * {
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
      }
      p {
        font-size: 16px;
      }
    `}
    onSizeUpdated={size => console.log(size.height)}
    source={{ html: `<p style="font-weight: 400;font-style: normal;font-size: 21px;line-height: 1.58;letter-spacing: -.003em;">Tags are great for describing the essence of your story in a single word or phrase, but stories are rarely about a single thing. <span style="background-color: transparent !important;background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(146, 249, 190, 1), rgba(146, 249, 190, 1));">If I pen a story about moving across the country to start a new job in a car with my husband, two cats, a dog, and a tarantula, I wouldn’t only tag the piece with “moving”. I’d also use the tags “pets”, “marriage”, “career change”, and “travel tips”.</span></p>` }}
    scalesPageToFit={true}
    viewportContent={'width=device-width, user-scalable=no'}
    /*
    other react-native-webview props
    */
  />
```

Comment: Will this work if I have a content wrapper that's full height, and I only want to show a specific div within that element?